# read in specific values from a file and store them in a list python

Tags: python, list, coordinates

I have a file in the following format:

```
-2000 -2000 -2000 # (*THE FRAME, origin point*), 1
-2000 379 -2000 # 2
 2000 379 -2000 # 3
 2000 -2000 -2000 # 4
-2000 -2000 -2000 # 1
j
 2000 379 -1190 # 7
 2000 -2000 -1190 # 8
-2000 -2000 -1190 # 5
```

I need to read this file in python and store it in a list in the following format:

```
[[[-2000, -2000, -2000], [-2000 379 -2000], [2000, 379, -2000], [2000, -2000, -2000], [-2000, -2000, -2000]],[[2000, 379, -1190], [2000, -2000, -1190], [-2000, -2000, -1190]]]
```

so far I have read the file in and stored the values in a list

```
file = open('filename', 'r')
vlist = file.readlines()
file.close
```

then I turn each of the "j" values into [-1,-1,-1] and use that value as a break between lists.

```
points = []
points = [list(map(int,elem.split())) if elem.strip().lower() != "j" else [-1, -1, -1]     for elem in vlist]
```

and then using itertools i am able to split this list into groups that are divided everytime [-1,-1,-1] occurs in the list:

```
pointLists = [list(group) for val, group in groupby(points, lambda x: x == [-1,-1,-1]) if not val]
```

this i believe would give me my desired output however it does not work for the file example I showed up top because it does not remove the #'s and the values that follow it.

i am not sure how to go about removing the #'s and the values that follow from the list so any help would be a great help Thanks.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: this feels like deja vu

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602621/storing-data-from-a-file-into-a-list-python :)

Comment: @Vik2015 Ahh, no wonder.

Comment: Do _any_ of our answers, answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [l.split() for l in f.readlines()]
lines = [map(float, l[:3]) for l in lines if len(l)>=3]
```

this will take only the three first columns of the lines with >= 3 columns and convert all the values to float.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't actually need `[-1,-1,-1]` in between for the final result:

```
with open('stuff') as f:
    list1 = [line.strip().split('#')[0].split() for line in f]
    print [[map(int, var) for var in g] for k, g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: len(x)==1) if k != 1]
```

This will work regardless how many columns or rows each line has.

Answer (score 0):

That code gets what you need

```
file = open('test', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close

a = []
b = []
t = a
for line in lines:
    temp = line.split('#')
    if len(temp) == 1:
        t = b
        continue
    t.append(map(int, temp[0].strip().split(' ')))

list = [a,b]
print list
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex...

```
import re
f = open("file.txt")
data = f.readlines()
f.close()
output = []
final = []
for line in data:
    l = re.findall("[0-9\-]+|[j]", re.sub("[#](.+)", "", line))
    if l == ['j']:
        final.append(output)
        output = []
        continue
    output.append([float(i) for i in l])
if output:
    final.append(output)
for i in final: print i
```